# C SHARP How to exclude certain number calculation

Tags: c#

How can I block the Divide Zero by Zero calculation. My calculator is allowed to do a | + | - | * | calculation but I don't want it to execute a zero by zero calculation with dividing.

thanks!

```
protected void btnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double get1;
    double get2;

    double answer;
    get1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtGetal1.Text);
    get2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtGetal2.Text);
    answer = get1 / get2;
    txtUitkomst.Text = Convert.ToString(answer);
}
```

I receive a NaN

Comment: Test before dividing.

Comment: `if (denominator == 0) { don't do division }` seems rather obvious...

Answer (score 3):

You can check before dividing and return 0 if denominator is zero.

```
protected void btnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double get1;
    double get2;

    double answer;
    get1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtGetal1.Text);
    get2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtGetal2.Text);
    answer = (get2==0) ?0 : get1 / get2; // check for 0 and return 0
    txtUitkomst.Text = Convert.ToString(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you would have to check in input. If the user tries to enter a value of zero as the second argument of the division, your program has to reject the input and prompt the user to enter a nonzero value.